# Theoretical: about php, mysql, comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with employees. the columns are first name, last name, department, internal number etc..

As for today it is a database only for one organization but in future i want to add to this database employees from other relative organizations.

What is the right way to do it:

1. To add another field to the first table ?
2. To create another table with 3 fields: id, organization_name, employees ( where in this filed i would put comma separated values of id from first table) ?

if the second answer will be chosen what will happened when an update query will be executed simultaneously from different accounts to the same organization. For example: i will be adding a user with id 55 to organization 'Police' and at the same time another administrator will be adding to the same organization a user with id 65..
In this case is there a possibility of error or data-loss ???

If someone had this kind of problem before, i really would like to read about it..
Thank You..

Comment: Keep databases relational... storing comma-separated values in a column inevitably leads to all kinds of problems... normalize

Comment: @MarkBaker, still trying to understand the practical meaning of database normalization..
I have read a lot about it but didn't have any chance to practice it.. This database is my first scenario where i should consider everything.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes to the intent of #1.  Basically, you would add an organization table, which contains the unique list of organizations (one per row) in the system.  Then you have to decide how your existing tables relate to the organization table.  You might decide the department table is related to the organization table, so you add the org_id to that table, assuming a department is related to only one organization.  If you decide there's a many to many relationship involving organization, you would add a mapping table. Example dept_org table which contains (dept_id, org_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the organization is only a number to group the users, then I would suggest to put them into the employees table. However if you have more information about the organization (e.g. name, address .. ) then make a new table for the organization and save the primary key of the corresponding organization in the employees-table.

Comment: You're welcome. Also with this approach, you don't have the proplem you mentioned in the second question.